# maven sprinbootest junit 5 is not populating properly database with dates

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, unit-testing, junit

I'm working with springboot and JPA and I have a problem to pass tests with maven. When I run from IDE they passed.

The problem is related with dates.I have this insert at resources/data.sql:

INSERT INTO orders (order_id, number, client_id, created_on)
values (2, '0002', 1, '2021-11-21 16:12:20.414' );

but when I recover order_id = 2 the created_on date is null

This only happens when I run with mvn install, Running the test directly from the IDE has the date properly set.

pom dependencies:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

any idea?

thanks

Comment: First I see that you have defined hibernate etc. manually with versions which is in general the wrong way in a spring boot project... let spring boot define the versions you are using. Furthermore you have defined junit as a dependency but have not defined the scope of junit as test...also I would recommend to use a more recent version of spring boot (2.6.0) instead of an old one..which is EoL

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without seeing tests, but I think, the problem lays in date format in DB and date format which you pass through test. Database receives incorrect format, so it puts in null.
If you could show some code, maybe I can be of more help.